# How to Pass The Values of Function Parameters and run Standalone Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

From the documentation, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone

**Running a standalone script**

After writing a script, there are two ways to run a function from the script editor:

- Select the Run menu, followed by the name of the function you want to execute.
- Choose the name of the function you want to execute from the select box in the toolbar, then click ▶.

It does not tell us how to pass the parameter values to the functions I want to run.

So how could I pass the parameter values to the functions and run these functions?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I could understand about what you want. When you want to run a function from the same project by giving values, how about this? In the case of this script ``function run() {main("foo")}; function main(v){}``, run ``run()``. By this, ``main(v)`` can get ``"foo"`` and run. If you want to run a function from other project, how about using [scripts.run of Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) or [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)? These methods can give values when the function is run.

Comment: @Tanaike, I am coding the Google Apps Scripts for non developer to use. scripts.run  will work. But still it is not very straightforward for non developer to submit the parameters in json request body. I saw a hacking solution, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound, instead of standalone, bound the script to Google sheet. and read the "parameters values" from Google Sheet Cells. This way, the user just need to fill up or change the values of Google Sheet Cells, the values will be read into the Google Apps Script functions.

Comment: I'm really sorry my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike, your comment is helpful. :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If you have issues for your situation, feel free to tell me. I would like to think of the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google Apps Script editor Run feature doesn't offer a direct way to pass parameters to functions so we have to create a helper function to be called by this feature which in time will call the function of interest with the required parameters.

The above is the that we should do to test trigger functions that require an event object as parameter as is described on [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)